# make it non-clickable after clicked (connect 3 game)

Tags: java, android

i'm a beginner. i'm trying to build the connect 3 game from scratch for practice. and every time i click on a square, it changes colors. this is what i have so far...

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    // 0 = yellow 1 = red

    int activePlayer = 0;

    // 2 means unplayed

    int[] gameState = {2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2};

    public void dropIn (View view) {

        ImageView counter = (ImageView) view;

        System.out.println(counter.getTag().toString());

        int tappedCounter = Integer.parseInt(counter.getTag().toString());

        if (gameState[tappedCounter] == 2) {

            gameState[tappedCounter] = activePlayer;

        }

        counter.setTranslationY(-1000f);

        if (activePlayer == 0) {

            counter.setImageResource(R.drawable.yellow);

            activePlayer = 1;

        } else {

            counter.setImageResource(R.drawable.red);

            activePlayer = 0;

        }

        counter.animate().translationYBy(1000f).rotation(360).setDuration(300);

    }

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
    }
}
```

what am i doing wrong?

[what i don't want it to do](https://i.stack.imgur.com/G8FGS.png)

Comment: what is your issue?

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. We can help you more easily when you ask a specific question. What do you want your code to do that it isn't doing now? Is it doing something that you don't want? What is it? In this case, some screenshots of your program as it runs will help us understand your question better.

Comment: sorry about that. added a pic.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is how you can make a button non-clickable after oneclick.

```
boolean x = false;

method {
    if(!x) {
        normal process;
    }
    else {
        do nothing;
    }
    x = true;
}
```

The onClick method will only run once as the value will of boolean variable will stay true after the first execution of onClick method

Comment: I don't think you want an assignment inside your if condition... In fact, with booleans you shouldn't be using an operator at all `if (x), if (!x)`

Comment: thanks for the info. but how do i put that into my code?